# How to Record VOIP calls on a ROOTED device?

Tags: java, android, voip, audio-recording, rooted-device

I'm currently working on a project where I need to record VOIP Calls for apps like (Whatsapp and other app that uses VOIP for calling)

I have tried below code for triggering an event when whatsapp call is made so at the same time I have started audio recorder but here is the problem

```
recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    //i have tried VOICE_COMMUNICATION , VOICE_CALL but same issue 
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setOutputFile(file);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

try {
    recorder.prepare();

    recorder.start();
    checkRecording = true;
    Log.e("Audio", "recording starts") ;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.e("Audio", "recording stops") ;
            recorder.stop();
            checkRecording = false;
        }
    }, 60000);

} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("Audio stop", "error "+e) ;
}
```

**When audio recording starts and same time whatsapp call then receiver cannot listen to my voice but i can hear his voice and audio recorded only my voice - basically when recording starts it uses same audio source as whatsapp so then whatsapp block mic thats why reciever cant hear my voice**

I need a way to use same audio source with multiple app so when I start recording it should not busy mic so whatsapp can also use it?

So, anyone can help to record call over voip (Android studio) or guide me where Im doing it wrong or any suggestion would help me!

And I'm making this app for Emulator which is rooted so any kernal way for this also entertain

> and this question already been asked but never answered so please
>   anyone answer or suggest any solution to this issue

Comment: so can you tell me any other way to record voip calls or any way that audio recording don't engage mic while recording or in background and whatsapp can easily use it ?

Comment: @Toaster thanks for looking into this matter and you help :)
Bro, I have tried this CUBE CALL RECORDER app, issue is the same as mine, when I try whatsapp call and start recording, it shows me error message that audio source is not available . This is the same error as I'm facing now

Comment: @Toaster yes I have tried cube call recorder while whatsapp call and its failed to record showing me an error that audio source is already busy

Comment: @Toaster and also my voice not be hear at the other end as it blocks

Comment: I'm too frustrated bro as I need this to be done anyhow

Comment: bro you can use KO PLAYER emulator which is already rooted, or suggest me any way to play with root mic

Comment: thanks for looking into matter and helping me bro, appreciated much :)

Comment: Sure bro, I always try to do that help others

Comment: @Toaster thanks a ton bro for doing such efforts, some of very helping links to work on and I'm too searching an alternate solution for this but now will try above links thanks much :)

Comment: bro can you guide me how to run and what to expect as output of above binary file? I tried exec this bin file in emulator and tried whatsapp call but nothing display or happened

Comment: @Toaster bro you there?

Comment: it's worked at last? @Toaster,

Answer (score 0):

VoIP calls cannot be recorded as of now in Android.

Normal Calls dont use microphone so another app can acquire microphone and record the conversation.

But in VoIP calls, the app would be using the microphone so another app cannot acquire, if it tries it fails with an error. If the app tries to acquire microphone before the VoIP call then during the call the other side will not be able to hear anything.

So bottom line is there is no such app as of now to record VoIP calls in Android.

Cube call recorder or any spy app claiming to record VoIP calls won't record on majority of the phones (even if rooted). They might work on some Chinese phones which might be having dual microphone.

Comment: But some apps are recording whatsapp calls so how can you say that? Is there something that we are missing?